# type error occurred using buffer memoryview

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, xbee

I wanted to do a program which gets data from serial port which start and stop bit will be ***** and **#**. Data received will be in  ***1234567#**  this form. But it says my 'type' object is not subscriptable. I'm really new to Python i don't know what to do next, can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)

MAX_BUF_SIZE = 16
bits = 0

v = memoryview



print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)



while(1):
    for memoryview in ser.read():
        if v[0] == 42:

            if v[-1] == 35:

                print(v[1:-1].tobytes())

        else:
            memoryview = 0
ser.close()
```

---

```
connected to: COM5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Saves\Receive using buff.py", line 24, in <module>
    if v[0] == 42:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

Comment: What is `memoryview` initially? You assign it to v. Basically the error says you can't use [] operator for v in `v[0]`

Comment: @Juho: `memoryview` is a built-in.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is wildly over-complicated. I have no idea why you are using `memoryview` at all. Just do this:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
for data in ser.read():
    if data[0] == 42 and data[-1] == 35:
           print(data[1:-1].decode())
ser.close()
```

This is unlikely to actually work as you want, but it's a simplification of your code.
How to *actually* handle it depends on how the data looks more in detail.

Comment: That `v` probably should be `data`

Comment: @user2294001: That is, as I mentioned, quite likely. I don't even have a serial port to test it with, much less the serial device you have connected. I just fixed what I could see was wrong with your code as related to your question about the type error. If you misuse pyserial or your serial device is another question. My answer answers the question and should be selected as the correct answer. Further problems you have should be posted as new questions.